# Как скопировать значения одного List<> в другой ,на другой сцене?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Во время запуска я записываю в лист некие значения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне скопирать эти значения в другой лист на другой сцене?
Пробовал через static , просто не получается я не знаю уже 3 часа голову ломаю , не могу найти гайды рабочие.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое простое, создайте объект, набросьте на него тег, или по типу класса ищите, закиньте в него данные изначально и имейте доступ к нему отовсюду. Не надо передавать список, пусть он лежит в месте, которое доступно везде. Про `ScriptableObject` почитайте.

Comment: Я добавляю данные не в эдиторе , а прямо во время игрового процесса, после остановки игры данные ресетаются

Comment: Не имеет значения, где вы их добавляете. Имеет значение, где они хранятся.

Comment: Может быть есть еще какой нибудь сопособ?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй разобраться в [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html). Он позволит сохранять данные в файле в Resourse (к примеру) и использовать их повторно в другой сцене.

При этом учитывай, если тебе нужно удалять данные при выключении игры, то надо будет заранее продумать сброс значений в этом файле.